# Deploying Resources with Play! Framework

Tags: configuration, playframework

My web application uses MyBatis ORM. As a part of this, I have the typical mybatis.xml config file along with mappers for my SQL. When running the Play! server, the directory with these resources is not picked up and added to the classes directory.

Is there a way to configure Play! to include this directory in it's load/deploy process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With Play 1.x the simplest way to do this is to put your files in the conf directory which is in the classpath